# I cant send Extra for singleTask activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I use singleTask activity in my application.
Order activities A->B->C->B
I put extra on A and then get it on B, then I go to C and try `putExtra` for B, but on B I don't see it.

If I use default `android:launchMode`, it work ok.

Comment: try to check onNewInten method in B activity http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManifestForTasks

Comment: for getting dont use putExtra,instead use getExtra in B

Comment: define "i don't see it". (and onNewIntent is probably what you want indeed)

Answer (score 1):

you have to carry extra between intents.

A -step1-> B -step2-> C -step3-> B

**step1**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            String extraString;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            extraString = null;
            System.out.println("null extra");
        } else {
            extraString = extras.getString("extra");
            System.out.println("from " + extraString);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(C.this,B.class);
            intent.putExtra("extra", extraString);
        startActivity(intent);
    };
```

**step2**

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    String extraString,extraString2;


            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras == null) {
                extraString = null;                             
                System.out.println("null extra");
            } else {
                   try
                       {
                   extraString = extras.getString("extra");
                   System.out.println("from " + extraString);
                       {
                       catch{}
            }


                   // CATCH EXTRA STRING2

                    if (extras == null) {
                extraString2 = null;
                System.out.println("null extra");
            } else {
                       try
                       {
                   extraString2 = extras.getString("extra2");
                   System.out.println("from " + extraString2);
                       {
                       catch{} 
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(C.this,B.class);
                    intent.putExtra("extra", extraString);
            startActivity(intent);
        };
```

**step3**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            String extraString
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        extraString = null;
        System.out.println("null extra");
    } else {
        extraString = extras.getString("extra");
        System.out.println("from " + extraString);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(C.this,B.class);
            intent.putExtra("extra2", extraString);
    startActivity(intent);
};
```

Comment: From A to B I send extra1, but from C to B extra2

Comment: As I see, your answer good for default android:launchMode, for android:launchMode="singleTask" answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051507/how-to-send-data-to-created-activity-on-android/14052145#14052145