# How to send data to created activity on Android

Tags: android

I need to send data from EditText in activity A to Activity B.
I tried:

```
Intent intent1=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent1.putExtra("fromA", "text");
startActivity(intent1);
```

But It doesn't work, because activity B has `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and was created before.

How else, can I send data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You override `onNewIntent()` in the `Activity B` and receive the `intent` in that method.

Like below code:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent i)
{
  String s = i.getStringExtra("fromA");
}
```

In the above code you will get value to `s` from `Activity A`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by iPhone way. Create a class where you can set data before starting new activity and access the same data from new activity.

This will work as follows

1. There are two activities *FirstActivity* and *SecondActivity*
2. Data to be send is first name and last name

so there will be one class where you will have variable for the data

```
 public class DataTransporter{
      public static String firstName;
      public static String lastName;
 }
```

In first activity your code will be

```
 DataTransporter.firstName = "abc";
 DataTransporter.lastName = "xyz"; 
 Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class)
 startActivity(intent)
```

In second activity you can fetch this data

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   String first = DataTransporter.firstName;
   String last = DataTransporter.lastName;
 }
```

You can remove the data from transporter class (if needed) once fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using SharedPreferences to save my data and use it throughout my classes , plus they will be saved to the device , making them available even after the app is killed ... Here is an example for ya !

```
//Some String that I should remember, I am just using the package name for now
String app = this.getPackageName();/*This is going to be used more like a file to save my stuff to*/
//Setting our sharedpreferences
SharedPreferences sha = sha = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(app, SherlockActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);


String myString = "This is the String that you want to save so you can use among your classes"

//Now we call in an editor for that SharedPreferences so we can write and delete stuff from it .

Editor edit = sha.edit();

//Now we insert our String.
edit.putString("Something_you_can_remember" , myString);//You will need the "Something_you_can_remember" a few lines ahead , so remember it !
edit.apply(); //Or we can use edit.commit() , but I prefer apply()

//Now our String is saved ! So lets read it !

String whatever = sha.getString("Something_you_can_remember" , "The String incase myString didn't even exist , saves you from a NullPointerException");

//Here we go ! Now we have our String saved and can be readable among the classes !
```

Also , if you wanted to delete that String or whatever you "put" in there , you can call

```
edit.remove("Something_you_can_remember"); //or edit.clear() to remove all the values stored !
```

Hope this helps !